# Closed over value not picked up in Mongoose Map function

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to create a dynamic map function - ie the use an arbitrary field to aggregate on. I thought I would be able to use a closure for this but it does not work - I get an error stating blah is not defined.

My test code -

```
o.map = (function(){
        var blah = 'skill';
        var mapIt = function() {
            for (var idx = 0; idx < this[blah].length; idx++) {
                var key = this.skill[idx];
                var val = 1;
                emit(key, val);
            }
        }
        return mapIt
    })()
```

Regards,
Sean

Comment: This seems to work -  o.scope = {'blah': blah};

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the map function is actually getting sent over the wire via function `toString` (in source code form) to mongodb for execution inside mongodb itself (not node). Thus, this doesn't work. This is what the `scope` option is for. Any data you need to supply as context/arguments/scope to the map/reduce job needs to be set in the `scope` object.

Comment: Thanks for the insight Peter, i thought that may have been the case and even attempted to use eval to construct a function with the dynamic value hard coded - but hapi didn't seem to like it.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have to set scope manually -

o.scope = {'blah': blah};